# Inserterting JLabel into JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcombobox

http://prntscr.com/1gpdqe

Sorry for the link it's my first time in this forum.

Can anyone please help me?

I've been trying to make an image and a text show together in one line on a **JComboBox**, after searching on sites, I could not find a solution to my problem.

The **JLabel** above the **JLabel** works but the **JLabel** in the **JComboBox** doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this example will sort things out:

On `getListCellRendererComponent` I used `Label` + `Icon`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class ShowConboWithIcons extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final ImageIcon INFO_ICON  = new ImageIcon("info.png");
private static final ImageIcon NONE_ICON  = new ImageIcon("none.png");
public final String NONE_STR = "None";
private final String INFO_STR = "Info";

private JComboBox comboBox;
private JPanel    topPanel;

private String[] str_arr = null; 


public ShowConboWithIcons(String[] str_arr) {
    this.str_arr = str_arr;     
}


public void createGUI(){

    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    setTitle("Demo");
    setLocation(200, 200);

    topPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Map<Object, Icon> icons = new HashMap<Object, Icon>(); 

    icons.put(NONE_STR, NONE_ICON); 
    icons.put(INFO_STR, INFO_ICON); 

    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setRenderer(new IconListRenderer(icons));
    comboBox.addItem("None");

    for(String val : str_arr){
        comboBox.addItem(val);
    }

    topPanel.add(comboBox);

    super.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {           
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {              
            dispose();          
        }           
    }); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel" );   

    String[] str_arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    ShowConboWithIcons T = new ShowConboWithIcons(str_arr);
    T.createGUI();
    T.setVisible(true);        
}


class IconListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<Object, Icon> icons = null; 

    public IconListRenderer(Map<Object, Icon> icons){ 
        this.icons = icons; 
    } 

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    { 
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 

        // Get icon to use for the list item value 
        Icon icon = icons.get(value); 

        if(!value.toString().equals(NONE_STR)){
            icon = icons.get(INFO_STR);
        }

        // Set icon to display for value 
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        return label; 
    } 
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the example :-) An aside: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 5):

Don't insert a `JLabel` into a `JComboBox`. Use a `ListCellRenderer` instead. Read [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Comment: As if anyone can make sense of that example.

Comment: @7stud whoever can't shouldn't develop software ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra, That's like saying, "If you don't understand Java, you shouldn't program in java."  In that case, let's remove the java and swing tags from so.

Comment: What's with the downvote? That's not only the official example but is short and works perfectly

Comment: @7stud that's not what I meant and you know it (except if your intention is throwing dirt at java, no matter what) - translating for the sake of clarity: "anyone who can't make sense of the example [cited by trashgod] shouldn't develop software - because they don't have the energy/brains/intention to try solving a problem"

Answer (score 0):

U could Use JComboBox & JLabel both separately , JComboBox will have Strings & it will have action listener , JLable will diplasy Icon accordingly .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).